# Samsung Smart TV and Android

Tags: android, samsung-smart-tv

is it possible to create a connection between an Android app and a Samsung Smart TV app to transfer data between both apps?
I have already found the NService API, but it looks like that it can be used between Web Apps only and not with an Android app. 
Are the any other possibilities?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes of course, it's possible with MultiScreen SDK. You create application for Smart TV like a host and client for android phones. From your phone you can find TV, launch Smart TV application and connect to it and send any data using bidirectional transfer. See more:

[Samsung MultiScreen SDK](http://multiscreen.samsung.com/)

Comment: Does the TV require an internet connection or a WiFi together with the smartphone to transfer data between smartphone and TV? What is the technology behind the MultiScreen SDK?

Comment: MultiScreen SDK uses WebSockets and another web protocols from the box. Yes, TV and phone should be connected to same WiFi network.

Comment: Thanks. Is the Smart TV app installed on the device or does it require an internet connection to download the app on every app start?

Comment: As i know, smart tv app should be installed.

Comment: Which tv devices are compatible with the Samsung MultiScreen SDK? What are requirements for it?

Comment: All 2013-2014 Samsung TVs with Smart TV. About 2012 i didn't test it.